# Moment Generating Functions

Tags: probability

Suppose one is given an arbitrary moment generating function $M_{X}(t)$. How would you determine $P(X=k)$ from this? We know that $M_{X}(t) = E[e^{tX}]$ and $M_{X}(0) = 1$.

Comment: The inverse Laplace transform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$M_X(\log(t))$ is the probability generating function. Differentiate $k$ times and set $t=0$. Divide the result by $k!$.

Comment: $M_{X}(\log(t))$ is the probability generating function because $E[e^{x\log t}] = E[t^x]$?

Comment: Also the coefficient of $e^{kt}$ gives $P(X=k)$.